# Can single JWT token can be accessed by all users in rest API call

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-security, jwt

I have been using JWT token in my spring application. I have created a token for each customer passing username and password as a parameter to generate token, but this token is accessed by all users.

For example: Customer 3 has to get his data `http://example.com/api?customer=3`

customer 3 has to pass a token in header and he can access this url..

But the same token can be used to get other customer data  `http://example.com/api?customer=4

How do I restrict this?

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, 
                                HttpServletResponse response, 
                                FilterChain filterChain) 
                                        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {

        String jwt = getJwt(request);
        if (jwt!=null && jwtProvider.validateJwtToken(jwt)) {
            String username = jwtProvider.getUserNameFromJwtToken(jwt);

            UserDetails userDetails = userService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication 
                    = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
            authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Can NOT set user authentication -> Message: {}", e.getMessage());
    }

    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}

private String getJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

    if (authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        return authHeader.replace("Bearer ","");
    }

    return null;
}

public String generateJwtToken(Authentication auth) {
    UserPrinciple userPrinciple = (UserPrinciple) auth.getPrincipal();

    return Jwts.builder()
            .setSubject(userPrinciple.getUsername())
            .setIssuedAt(new Date())
            .setExpiration(expiryDate())
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, "secretKey")
            .compact();
}

public Date expiryDate() {
    return new Date((new Date()).getTime() + 15 * 60 * 1000);
}

public boolean validateJwtToken(String authToken) {
    try {
        Jwts.parser().setSigningKey("secretkey").parseClaimsJws(authToken);
        return true;
    } catch (SignatureException e) {
        logger.error("Invalid JWT signature -> Message: {} ", e.getMessage());
    } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
        logger.error("Invalid JWT token -> Message: {}", e.getMessage());
    } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
        logger.error("Expired JWT token -> Message: {}", e.getMessage());
    } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
        logger.error("Unsupported JWT token -> Message: {}", e.getMessage());
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        logger.error("JWT claims string is empty -> Message: {}", e.getMessage());
    }

    return false;
}

public String getUserNameFromJwtToken(String token) {
    return Jwts.parser()
                        .setSigningKey("secretKey")
                        .parseClaimsJws(token)
                        .getBody().getSubject();
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should generate a token for each user, instead one token for all users

Comment: You need to get user information from access token and then check if user is accessing his own information

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Would be interesting to see how are you actually generating the JWT for each user and include a bit more info about the behaviour that you expect on your app.  Since one of the reserved claims of the JWT is the  "sub", which is the subject of the JWT (i.e the user) and there is another field that is the "aud" which specifies for what that token is intended for. You could easily check who is actually calling to the endpoint and if it's authorised or not for that.

Comment: Actually, I think that you authorized the customer that he can access http://example.com/api path. I think PreAuthorize spring annotation can help you. Take a look here how I used PreAuthorize annotation to secure my endpoint. https://github.com/Calimerico/eventify/blob/master/eventify-backend/event/src/main/java/com/eventify/event/api/rest/EventController.java
And here is custom permissionService https://github.com/Calimerico/eventify/blob/master/eventify-backend/event/src/main/java/com/eventify/config/security/PermissionService.java

Comment: @JaimeS I can understand that creating a token that will validate secret key, algorithm and the username(Jaime) which is checking whether exist in our database.

Let's say you're creating another account and generating a token with new username(Nishanth) and password.

Instead of using my token, what will happen if I use your token to get access to other APIs. It will validate secret key , algorithm which is same for all the customer and user name which is checking whether you're exist or not in our database. So JaimeS username exist in our database.

Comment: @NishanthanP Access tokens are not meant to be shared and you must be kept confidential in transit and in storage; In OAuth all communication should be under SSL because tokens are like passwords, and if someone intercepted your token can be used immediately by an attacker. The API must check that access tokens are valid only for as short time as possible and then use the refresh token (with a longer expiration time) to refresh the access token. It's all documented in the OAuth RFC including countermeasures to attacks https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6819#section-4.1.3